# Did drag setting changed in PhysicsJS?

Tags: javascript, physicsjs

I can see drag working in this fiddle using PhysicsJS 0.5.2: http://jsfiddle.net/slacktracer/z7DmA/ but it doesn't work using 0.6.0: http://jsfiddle.net/slacktracer/z7DmA/5/.

Both should have the same drag:

```
world.add(Physics.integrator('verlet', {
    drag: 0.5
}));
```

Did something (about drag) changed? (`subscribe` changed to `on`, I saw that)

The first fiddle is using this file:
http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/examples/physicsjs-full.js

And the second is using this file:
http://anzol.biz/physicsjs/physicsjs-full-0.6.0.js
(it's just the latest dist on github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did not change. This is a bug. https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/issues/94